# How to publish Google Analytics visitor map on my Google Site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

Is it possible to publish google analytics audience location map (visitors) on my google site? My idea is to have it displayed and to consider the max period of time. If the viewers from new countries come up, the map is basically updated as it always considers e.g. 2018-now period of time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set chart options based on the options allowed by the various Google chart libraries. Here's the Google chart documentation for the chart type GEO:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options